# sql 'shows' array on some columns

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, post

I have some basic code which collects chkbox & radio buttons yes/no answers etc. from a form and stores in mysql but some of the mysql submissions work (ie puts yes or no in the sql column) but some just show in sql column as 'array' - this is a sample of the code.  $repeat shows as 'array' where as $inter shows as yes or no.  The columns in mysql are identical in structure the form HTML is the same syntax for both, the $_POST arrays are comma separated as I also email the values and the email displays the answers correctly - this is just odd

```
<?php
$repeat = "";
foreach ($_POST['repeat'] as $key => $value) {
$repeat.= ",$value ";
}
$repeat = substr($repeat,1);

$inter = "";
foreach ($_POST['intermitant'] as $key => $value) {
$inter.= ",$value ";
}
$inter = substr($inter,1);

//other posts all looped though etc
//then the sql - log on etc

$sql="INSERT INTO faults (repeat_visit,intermitant) VALUES ('$repeat','$inter')";
```

This is the HTML - Nothing odd about it that I can see, I get what you describe above - but why does one work and the other not with the same code, the  same method is applied to checkboxes and some wiork fine other put 'array' in sql

```
<label>Repeat Visit:</label>
<input type="radio" name="repeat[]" value="Yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="repeat[]" value="No" />No

<label>Intermitant Fault:</label>
<input type="radio" name="intermitant[]" value="Yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="intermitant[]" value="No" />No
```

Comment: Please show us the form html

Comment: re `$repeat=''`, `.=` and `substr` try `$repeat=array();`, `$repeat[]=$value;` and to stringify `$repeat=implode(',', $repeat);`

Answer (score 0):

As popnoodles stated, seeing the form's HTML would help, but this looks as if each element in $_POST['repeat'] & $_POST['intermitant'] is actually an array, and so the $value of the foreach() is returning "Array"

Check that the checkbox array is only 1 dimensional, and if it is not, does it have to be multi-dimensional?

If so, perhaps a recursive function or nested loop to implode the values is required

```
$repeat = "";
foreach ($_POST['repeat'] as $k => $v)
{
    foreach ($v as $kInner => $vInner)
    {
         $repeat .= ",$vInner ";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the HTML - Nothing odd abouit it that I can see, I get what you describe above - but why does one work and the other not with the same code